# Someone suggest me some resources of NFT Pallet frontend react implementation?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, polkadot, pallet

I am using [nft-pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/b9b1bbb7cc0fc184ea8881ddaa7e92b91baa1925/frame/nfts) for nft creation. I have implemented in substrate node. Now I wan't to write my own code not `polkadotjs` to create with nft using `nft pallet` using react frontend. Someone please suggest some resources.

Comment: This can give you an idea on how to start: https://polkadot.study/tutorials/kitties-part-01/step7